# laravel 5.2 search in related entity

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-5

Suppose I have a Model called 'Commodity' which has category_id belongs to a category.

In Commodity.php I defined this relationship:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Now, I want to find the commodities which their category name include 'glass'

I tried this:

```
$items = Commodity::orderBy('id', 'desc')->category()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%glass%');
```

But it populates this error:

> **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read official documentation that covers [querying relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the eager loading query. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>    
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
>
> }])->get();
> ```

So, regarding your question I'd suggest to try next:

```
$commodities = App\Commodity::with(['category' => function ($query) {
    
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%glass%');

}])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```